# Asking a kernel to create an instance of a singleton scope dependency at module load

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject

My ASP.NET MVC 3 application uses Ninject IoC container. One of controllers depends on a data provider, that needs to start caching potentially required stuff when the web site starts, not when the controller is created on request and data is needed right a way.

So for this, I need to ask Ninject to create a singleton scope instance of my dependency, that it will that feed on requests on site start.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just performing whatever operation in global.asax on application started override that NinjectHttpApplication provides. If you are using a regular HttpApplicaiton (without the NinjectHttpApplication override) in your global.asax, then just use the regular HttpApplication_Start event to do your initialisation of the cache. Touching the IoC container in this context is acceptable as it is the composite root of your application. So I guess something like:

```
Bind<IProvider>().To<CacheProvider>().InSingletonScope(); //<in binding module

Kernel.Get<IProvider>().SetupCache() //<in global.asax
```

I dont really see any need for it to be more complicated than this... I could be wrong though.

If you can provide more detail about the provider, i can give a more specific suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add `.InSingletonScope()` to your mapping inside your kernel. This way, it will always use the same object. As soon as the object is needed, Ninject will load it, and always use the same object thereafter.

Comment: Thanks, but I have explicitly mentioned that I need to know how to get  a dependency to initialize when the site starts. I am aware of how to create a singleton scoped dependencies. By now I am just calling a `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` in Global.asax for this.

Comment: Then, yes, you need to make a call that loads this, that is what I meant when I said that the object will be loaded when it is needed. If you are not using it, then there is no need to instantiate it otherwise.